# Optional Default Parameters?

Tags: python

When I run the following code the output is "None"? I'm trying to write a function that would print a random number between two values depending whether parameters are present or not.

```
import random
def randInt(min="", max=70):
  if min and max == False:
    return random.random() * 80
  elif min == False:
    return random.random() * max
  elif max == False:
    return random.random() * min + 100
print(randInt())
```

Comment: `if not min and not max:`

Answer (score 0):

You need to spell out the first test.

```
if min == False and max == False:
```

Or shorten it like:

```
if min == max == False:
```

Comment: Thank you! When I run the program the output is still "None". Am I missing anything else?

Comment: The default values are `""` and `70`, but you're checking for `False` and `False`.